# cron vs. anacron

Tags: cron, anacron

I've got a pretty good handle on how cron/anacron work on linux. My question is this:

1. anacron runs at login, and checks if it's been more than a day since the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` have run
2. anacron runs scripts in `/etc/cron.daily`, and updates the timestamp in `/var/spool/anacron/cron.daily`
3. anacron exits
4. computer stays on for more than 24 hours
5. cron runs and detects a time match for cron.daily
6. cron does nothing since `test -x anacrontab" == True`

If my computer runs for more than 24 hours, how does cron run the scripts in cron.daily (This is a Debian based distro)?

the default `/etc/crontab` (which is running every minute) tests for the presence (or more precisely, the -x bit) of `/usr/bin/anacron`, and ignores the `/etc/cron.daily` folder if it finds it, but it doesn't seem to restart anacron to do the work.

**EDIT:**

So cron DOES start anacron from the `/etc/cron.d` folder, but only if the computer is on and logged in at 7:30 am every day. After doing a little spreadsheet kung-fu, I've come to the conclusion that the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` will run anywhere between 1 minute and 31.5 hours apart.

Ex:

Scenario 1:

- log in at 11:59 pm on 5/23/2021
- assuming the anacron timestamp for `/etc/cron.daily` is older than 5/23/2021, anacron runs all the scrips in `/etc/cron.daily` and updates the timestamp to 5/23/2021
- log out
- log back in at 12:00 am on 5/24/2021
- anacron sees that the last run was 5/23/2021, and it is now 5/24/2021, so anacron runs all the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily`
- elapsed time between runs: 1 minute

Scenario 2:

- log in at 12:00 am on 5/23/2021
- assuming the anacron timestamp for `/etc/cron.daily` is older than 5/23/2021, anacron runs all the scrips in `/etc/cron.daily` and updates the timestamp to 5/23/2021
- computer stays on and logged in until 7:30 am on 5/23/2021
- cron runs anacron from its crontab file in `/etc/cron.d`
- since the timestamp is 5/23/2021, nothing happens
- computer stays on and logged in until 7:30 am on 5/24/2021
- cron runs anacron from its crontab file in `/etc/cron.d`
- anacron sees that the last run was 5/23/2021, and it is now 5/24/2021, so anacron runs all the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily`
- elapsed time between runs: 31.5 hours

Comment: Do you have `/etc/cron.d/anacron` and `/etc/cron.daily/0anacron`? That will run `anacron`'s daily tab from a daily cron job (`anacron -u cron.daily`).  I'm not sure what you mean by your sixth point.

Comment: anacron -u only updates the timestamps, but DOES NOT start anacron. The 0anacron just calls anacron -u. /etc/cron.d/anacron only starts anacron if the comnputer is on at 7:30 am.

Answer (score 0):

All the system `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, etc files include an entry to run **anacron** which in turn includes an entry to run **cron**. `/etc/crontab` includes entries for *run-parts* so that **anacron** is either run by *run-parts* or by **cron**.

Another file to consider is `/etc/anacrontab` which can override some of the effects of `/etc/crontab`

An important system **cron** related file is `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` which is a script used to initiate log rotation processing.

Ordinary user *crontabs* are executed independently of system cronjobs.

Note that `/etc/crontab` is not running every minute - activity is determined by the various crontab specifications.

Comment: /etc/cron.{daily, weekly, monthly} do include 0anacron, which updates the timestamps, but DO NOT start anacron. /etc/cron.d will start anacron, but only at 7:30 am.